# How to track the clickable element over a HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

I am creating a editor in which I have used kinetic js. In my editor there is dynamic text which are draggable, but in case of editing text I need to get the click element for individual text over the canvas so that when user click on a text I can track that and edit that text .

Here is the script

```
   var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
   container: 'editor',
   width: 600,
   height: 600
   });
   var boxLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
   var rectX = 0;
   var rectY = 0;

   stage.add(boxLayer);


       function add_text() {
          alert('test');
               var complexText1 = new Kinetic.Text({
               x: 25,
               y: 25,
               text: 'Designer',
               fontSize: 18,
               fontFamily: 'Calibri',
               fill: '#555',
               width: 150,
               padding: 20,
               align: 'center',

               draggable: true
               });
               boxLayer.add(complexText1);
               boxLayer.draw();

                complexText1.destroy();
               complexText1.on('mouseover', function() {
               this.fill('orange');
               });
       }
```

also I have user `complexText1.destroy();` and after this draggable function is not working . I am new in canvas editor so need help to create it, any help regarding this will be appreciable.

Comment: @oGeez I have not put this,its edited by one of the editor. Do you know the answer then please help me

Comment: Sorry...KineticJS does not have a text editor.

Comment: @markE I am creating a T-shirt editor where I need to put text which is dynamic and dragable

Comment: KineticJS text is draggable but KineticJS text is not directly editable by the user (no word processing capability).  You can programmatically change the text: yourText.text("this will be your new text");